# Why did the Discovery Crew treat this character as an enemy?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery

Why did Discovery's Crew treat

> Gabriel Lorca

as an enemy after they found out that

> he was from another universe?
>
> His goal was the overthrow of the Terran Empire.

Comment: This is very spoilery

Comment: It's not like he was acting like a borderline-evil narcissist from day one or anything. ;)

Comment: His goal was to take control of the Terran Empire in order to be even more evil - he claims the existing Emperor allowed the rebellion to thrive. It's not like he believes in Federation principles and wants to "dissolve" the Empire...

Comment: Someone lures your whole crew to an alternate universe to settle down his selfish goals. Well, how can you trust someone who does that?

Comment: And btw, his motive was not just to overthrow Phillipa but to also take her place.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Because they no longer trust him.

Up until Lorca's reveal, the crew believed him to be the Lorca of their Universe.  A man with a known history in Star Fleet, with a known reputation.

When it is revealed who Lorca really is, the crew can no longer trust him.  He's been lying to them for a long time; the crew can't be certain what was true and what wasn't.

So now they cannot trust his motives.  They cannot trust how much of their personal history with him is true.  They cannot trust how many of his orders were intended to further his plans.

Importantly, Mirror Lorca deliberately altered the spore drive to get to the Mirror universe.  This bought the Discovery crew into danger and nearly killed Stamets.

Treating him as an enemy is a defensive move: everything he does will now be met with suspicion and scrutiny.  Also, Lorca loses all his privileges and rights.  His previous orders can be ignored.

Answer (score 5):

Because he was revealed as a xenophobic megalomaniacal mass-murdering psychopath who lied to them might have something to do with it.